# Curl Request damages XML Post Data

Tags: php, xml, curl

I am sending XML data as a POST request with curl to server as follows:

```
    // $params contains xslt="<xml version ...."
    $url = get_cfg_var('Http_Host') . "/webservice/update.php?";
    $strParameters = http_build_query($params);

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    // Set options
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $strParameters);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
```

Now when I get the data in webserive/update.php

`$_REQUEST['xslt']` contains only some leaf data from xml with most of the tags stripped out like so [but with a lot of new lines]

```
 USD

  ,
  .


  0 
  5
```

I am at a loss to understand what is happening. Is it some double encoding issue?

strParameters does contain proper data in form-urlencoded format [+ for space etc.]

I tried a urldecode before sending it to curl. but it still doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: If you look into that data in a browser I would say: no wonder. It's XML and the browser will hide all tags it does not know. You might be looking for `htmlspecialchars` in that case.

Comment: No - I am not looking at that data in browser. I simply dumped the _REQUEST['xslt'] to a file at the server side.

Comment: I don't see an error in your code. The method looks good. Your server *might* alter the data. You could try to base64 encode the data and decode it in the script again and check if it goes through then.

Comment: Are you able to use a packet sniffer or other similar tool to see what the request looks like on the network before received at the server?

Comment: @hakre - yes that's exactly what I did now [and it works]. $params['xslt']=base64_encode(gzcompress($params['xslt'], 9)); Still I want to understand what is going on here. This is very weird.

Comment: You might have a web firewall on your server that is altering requests if it "thinks" that it's an attack. XML could look like a potential XSS and then it get's altered. Check with your hoster. You normally can disable such via .htaccess.

Comment: Thanks hakre - I am looking at firewalls, filters etc. You may want to post your base64 encode tip as an answer, as it helps getting around the issue. I will accept it. In any case if it is firewall/filter issue, it is no longer simply a programming issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is more a comment than a concrete solution, but I would consider to use the array method instead of encoding your own:

You don't need to encode the post-data yourself. You can directly use an array, [see](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php):

> **CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS**    The full data to post in a HTTP "POST" operation. [...] This parameter can either be passed as a urlencoded string like 'para1=val1&para2=val2&...' **or as an array with the field name as key and field data as value*. If value is an array, the Content-Type header will be set to multipart/form-data.